# Android App Hangs while downloading Parse Notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

My Android App hangs while it downloads the parse notification, image to be precise while the app is being used. Now I know a service can be started but I want to refrain from that. What should i do so that my app doesn't hang.

ParseReceiver.java

```
  public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver{

Bundle AnalyticsBundle;
String title = "";
String message = "";
String action_id = "";
String action_type = "";
String imageUrl = "";
String notType = "";
TripHomePage tripPageHome;

@Override
public void onPushReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    AnalyticsBundle=intent.getExtras();



    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        try {
            if (json.has("aps")) {
                json = json.getJSONObject("aps");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        if (json.has("title")) {
            title = json.getString("title").toString();
        }
        if (json.has("message")) {
            message = json.getString("message").toString();
        }

        if (json.has("action_type")) {
            action_type = json.getString("action_type").toString();

        }
        if (json.has("action_id")) {
            action_id = json.getString("action_id").toString();

        }
        if (json.has("url_image")) {

            imageUrl = json.getString("url_image").toString();

        }

        if (json.has("notification_type")) {
            notType = json.getString("notification_type").toString();
        }

        Boolean check=pref2.getBoolean("keyfornotification",true);
        if(check==true)
        {
            generateNotification(notType, title, message, action_id, action_type, imageUrl, context);

        }
        else if(check==false)
        {
            if(action_type.equals("UpdateApp"))
            {
                generateNotification(notType, title, message, action_id, action_type, imageUrl, context);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void generateNotification(String notType,String title, String message, String action_id, String action_type,String imageUrl,Context context){

    try {

            if (notType.equals("normalt") || notType.equalsIgnoreCase("NormalText")) {
                showtext(title, message, action_type, action_id, context);
            }
            if (notType.equals("bigi") || notType.equalsIgnoreCase("Bigimage")) {
                bigPicture(title, message, imageUrl, action_type, action_id, context);
            }
            if (notType.equals("overlay") || notType.equalsIgnoreCase("Overlay")) {
                bigOverlay(title, message, imageUrl, action_type, action_id, context);
            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}

public void showtext(String title, String message, String actionType, String actionId, Context context) {

    Bitmap tripotoLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.med);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context,
            (int) (Math.random() * 100), getIntent(actionType, actionId, context),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notif;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tripotoblack).setColor(Color.BLACK)
                .setLargeIcon(tripotoLogo).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(message))
                .build();
    } else {


        notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smalli)
                .setLargeIcon(tripotoLogo).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(message))
                .build();
    }


    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notif);


}

public void bigPicture(String title, String message, String url, String actionType, String actionId, Context context) {

    Bitmap tripImage = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL(url).openStream();
        tripImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap largeicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.smalli);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context,
            (int) (Math.random() * 100), getIntent(actionType, actionId, context),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Notification n;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(tripImage).setBigContentTitle(title).setSummaryText(message)).setTicker(title).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tripotoblack).setColor(Color.BLACK)
                .setLargeIcon(largeicon)
                .build();
    } else {


        n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(tripImage).setBigContentTitle(title).setSummaryText(message)).setTicker(title).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smalli)
                .setLargeIcon(largeicon)
                .build();


    }
    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, n);


}


public void bigOverlay(String title, String message, String url, String actionType, String actionId, Context context) {


    Bitmap tripImage = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL(url).openStream();
        tripImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.bigo);
    contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, tripImage);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, title);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, message);

    Bitmap largei = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.med);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context,
            (int) (Math.random() * 100), getIntent(actionType, actionId, context),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentInfo("Tripoto:")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tripotoblack).setContentText(message).setContentTitle(title).setColor(Color.BLACK)
                .setTicker(title).setLargeIcon(largei).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setPriority(2).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .setBigContentTitle(title).setSummaryText(message))
                .build();
    } else {

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentInfo("Tripoto:")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smalli).setContentText(message).setContentTitle(title)
                .setTicker(title).setLargeIcon(largei).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setPriority(2).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .setBigContentTitle(title).setSummaryText(message))
                .build();

    }
    notification.bigContentView = contentView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);


}

//==========bind intent for specific class=====
private Intent[] getIntent(String type, String id, Context context){
    Intent[] list = new Intent[2];
    switch (type) {
    case Constants.UpdateApp:

        /**
          * first intent will open play store for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          */
        try {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tripoto"));

         Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         mIntent.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);
         mIntent.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);

         list[0] = mIntent;
         list[1] = viewIntent;
         }catch(Exception e) {} 

        break;
    case Constants.trips:
    case Constants.trip:
        /**
          * first intent will open trip page for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          */


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TripHomePage.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ClickedTripIdKey, id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);

         Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         list[0] = mIntent;
         list[1] = notificationIntent;


        break;
    case Constants.users:
    case Constants.user:
        /**
          * first intent will open profile page for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          */
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileHomePage.class);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ClickedUserIdKey, id);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);

         Intent mIntent1 = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         list[0] = mIntent1;
         list[1] = notificationIntent;

        break;
    case Constants.blog:
        /**
          * first intent will open blog page for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          */
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BlogDetail.class);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ClickedBlogId, id);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);

         Intent mIntent2 = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         list[0] = mIntent2;
         list[1] = notificationIntent;
        break;
    case Constants.stash:
        /**
          * first intent will open stash page for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          */
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, InStashTrips.class);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ClickedTripkeyword, id);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);
         notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);

         Intent mIntent3 = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         list[0] = mIntent3;
         list[1] = notificationIntent;
        break;
    case Constants.publish_my_trip:
        /**
          * first intent will open create trip page for
          * update and second one will open the home page
          **/
        //======I've to use a blank intent coz of its size======:D
         notificationIntent = new Intent();
         Intent mIntent4 = new Intent(context, HomePageSlidingTab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         mIntent4.putExtra(Constants.isCalledFromParse, true);
         mIntent4.putExtra(Constants.ParseAnalytics, AnalyticsBundle);
         mIntent4.putExtra(Constants.isCalledForCreateTrip, true);

         list[0] = mIntent4;
         list[1] = notificationIntent;

        break;
    }


    return list;

}

}
```

Comment: We might be able to help you more if you post some code so we can see why it's hanging.

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

You're complaining because your App is hanging, yet you are doing this:

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

which is *deliberately* preventing Android from telling you that you are performing actions which might cause your App UI to hang!

In any case, it looks like you can just run the code in a separate thread (I couldn't see any UI updates, so it should be OK). You could try a simple runnable:

```
@Override
public void onPushReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
              // do real onPushReceive stuff here
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Or even a simple [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) (they're really not that hard to use):

```
@Override
public void onPushReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, com.example.MyNotificationService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra('com.example.mypushintent', intent)
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}

// In MyNotificationService.java
public class MyNotificationService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent serviceIntent) {
       Intent pushIntent = (Intent)serviceIntent.getParcelableExtra('com.example.mypushintent');
       // do stuff here
    }
}
```

In any case, it is always a good idea to minimise the work done directly in BroadcastReceivers and offload any heavy duty stuff to a thread or service.